# SQL Server - selecting a specific ID from a table

Tags: sql-server

I will explain what I have done so far and ask my question at the end.

First I created my external & internal variables (note that `@EDelivery` is a table type that included the columns `FoodID` and `Quantity`):

```
@EDelivery DeliveryTblType readonly
Declare @NumberOfMinutes smallint, @FoodWeight int, @WeightCapacity int, 
@DroneID int, @TimeOfWeek varchar
```

I then read this in, giving me the total weight of all items ordered and read in the weight capacity from the `DronesTbl`:

```
select @FoodWeight = SUM(FoodWeight * Quantity)
from @EDelivery as del
inner join Foods on del.FoodID = Foods.FoodID 

select @WeightCapacity = Drones.WeightCapacity
from dbo.Drones
```

My question is how do I select a specific drone to compare its weightcapacity to the food total weight

Comment: Your not using MySQL, MySQL doesn't support functions like GETDATE and throw. i've changed the MySQL tag into SQL-server tag

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the variable `@WeightCapacity` according to the @droneid value.  Right now,  you are setting this variable to last drone in your drones table.

If you change your second query  to what's below then it should work.

```
  select @WeightCapacity = 
     Drones.WeightCapacity
      from dbo.Drones
      where DroneID =@droneID
```

Comment: I dont know why I didnt see this, thanks for your help